# gawk field seperator as extended ascii

Tags: csv, gawk

I am using *gawk 3.1.7* on RHEL 6.x

I have large CSV files to parse with field seperator "Logical negation symbol / ALT + 170" ([View ASCII table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/logical-negation-symbol-ascii-code-170.html)), but I could not use it as field seperator in `gawk`.

I tried many things like `-F "\xaa"`, `-F "\252"`, but not worked.
Is there any way to use this character in gawk's field seperator?

BTW I created file with this character (there is only one character in file) and if I use it following way it's working.

```
-F "$(cat singleExtendedAsciiCharFile)"
```

However I think it's not safe (someone could delete this file). Do you have any idea for my issue?

Comment: Might be `awk -F $'\u0ac'`? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ac/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find hexadecimal code of the character:

```
$ echo -n '¬' | od -An -tx1
 c2 ac
```

And then prepend `\x` before each group of numbers:

```
$ awk -F '\xc2\xac'
```

Comment: It did not work,  please check screenshot out    https://pasteboard.co/GRY2fZ2.png

Comment: Show the output of `cat msuluhan | od -An -tx1`.

Comment: $ cat msuluhan | od -An -tx1
    ac 0a

Comment: awk -F "\xac\x0a" '{print $1"__"$2}'            is not working :/

Comment: @Murat `0a` is a newlne, so try just `awk -F '\xac'`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the character with the shell:

```
awk -F $'\xaa'
```

Comment: it's not working, I also tried before and tested again now, thanks

Comment: @Murat: (1) Did you notice that Hauke Laging’s answer features a **`$`** before the ``'…'``?  (2) This should work in bash.  What shell are you using?

Comment: Everything is default I mean I am using GNU Bash and gawk, I have uploaded a screenshot, please check it out   https://pasteboard.co/GRXZf79.png    PS: Sorry I have to obfuscate private data